# How to find a definite integral of half of an ellipse split along its major axis

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, conic-sections

I have the equation for the top half of an ellipse:

$$f(s) = \frac{2}{3\pi}\times \sqrt{1-\bigg(\frac{s-5}{3}\bigg)^2}$$

For one of my classes I have to find the integral from $2$ to $x$ of this function but I haven't learned integrals yet so I have no idea what to do. I think this is called a definite integral but again I am lost because I haven't learned about integrals.

Comment: Just in case this helps, if you don't know integrals and want to find the area of an ellipse you can do this using geometric linear transformations to transform the ellipse into a circle  and find : ($A_{ellipse}=\pi ab$)
Though this is from $2$ to $x$ so I don't know if geometric transformations can help you here.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you know that if we have a function $f(x)=x^n$ then we can differentiate this to give us $f'(x)=nx^{n-1}$

Integration is the opposite to this, in the same way that subtraction is the opposite to addition, we can say that $$\int f'(x)\,dx= \int nx^{n-1}\,dx=x^n+C$$

We must add the $+C$ as the original $f(x)$ could have had a constant which would have been turned to zero when it was differentiated $\left(f'(x^n+1)=f'(x^n+2)=\cdots =f'(x^n+C)=nx^{n-1}\right)$

We can then perform a definite integral as follows, for $a<b$:

\begin{align}\int_a^b f'(x)\,dx &= \int_a^b nx^{n-1}\,dx\\
&= \left[x^n+C\right]_{x=b}-\left[x^n + C\right]_{x=a}\\
&= b^n+C-a^n-C\\
&= b^n-a^n\end{align}

Does this help you solve your problem?

Comment: I understand the first part, but what do the brackets with subscript x=b and x=a mean? Apologies, it has been a while since I took Calc I or any math class.

Comment: The subscript $x=a$ means you substitute $a$ in place of $x$ in the expression in the brackets, and similarly for $x=b$